# I keep getting "Permission Denied" in Google Cloud terminal when trying to open Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to run Hadoop on a GCP.  When ever I type in the command

`start-dfs.ssh && start-yarn`

I get the following.......

```
localhost: chuckpryorjr@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
localhost: chuckpryorjr@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: chuckpryorjr@0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey).
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-ecosystem/hadoop-2.9.2/logs/yarn-chuckpryorj
r-resourcemanager-hadoopmasters.out
localhost: chuckpryorjr@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't get it.  Before they used to prompt me for a password(which I didn't ever recall making), now its just outright denying me.  How can make this passwordless?  Also the very first time I installed hadoop on GCP and ran it..it worked fine.  Sometimes I can get through to complete my work..sometimes I cant.

Comment: Is there a specific reason against using DataProc? Otherwise, seems like SSH keys were somehow updated to include a password or your SSH configs have changed to not allow that key

Comment: I dont know how to use Dataproc and I am training and this is how we are to access to hadoop...or via Virtualbox..but the laptop is archaic..so I am just using my mac and gcp

Comment: There's plenty of documentation on it... And would be much easier to get started with  https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials

Comment: I hv to follow wht my trainer saya

Comment: Alright, then. You've completed [these installation steps](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation) and can `ssh localhost` without issue, then?

Comment: OMG WTF....giving you a huuuuge cyber thank you!  The ssh localhost denied me..but I ran the code underneath and it got me in!

Answer (score 1):

> How can make this passwordless?

```
  $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then update your local authorized keys file for localhost

```
  $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  $ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And if you have other servers, you can use `ssh-copy-id` to place the key into those

Answer (score 0):

In my case when i added my Hadoop user to sudoer it worked fine.

```
sudo adduser hadoop sudo
```